# Session state changes on production, but not on test web server

Tags: web-config, iis-10, sessionid

I have a c# application that used IIS 10, that has been working for many years with using the session id to track the users selections across the site.

I did an update this week and I messed something up and I can't seem to pinpoint where the change was made.

I added a textbox on the same page on both test and production.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSession" ></asp:TextBox>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtSession.Text = Session.SessionID.ToString();
}
```

On test when I refresh the session id stays the same, but when I'm on production the session id changes when I refresh or go to a different page.  I'm reviewed my web.config on both sides and can't see where this is an issue.  This is the only session row in web.config on both side

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"/>
```

Within the global.asax.ca has the following

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 60;
    Session["User"] = "";
    Session["UserLevel"] = 0;
    Session["EmptyFields"] = -1;
    //Session["SelectedID"] = "";
}
```

So it is Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been going over this for almost 2 days and I can't seem to find the issue.  Part of my updated including updating to oracle managed data access dlls.  This also exists on test and it working fine.

Comment: How is httpCookies set in web.config? This may be related to httpCookies.

Comment: There is no httpCookies setting in the web.config.  It seems the issue was with 2 files that were deleted from the bin.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue was the following files were deleted from the bin directory.

> App_global.asax.compiled

> App_global.asax.dll

As soon as I copied them back everything started working.